# Grant site Members group Full Control of document library in SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, csom

Using CSOM in PowerShell, I am successfully breaking inheritance on a document library and removing the visitors group.

What I am failing to do is give the site Members group Full Control of that library.

This much works:

```
$SPOCredentials = New-Object 

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName,$password)

$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
$Ctx.Credentials = $SPOCredentials

$web = $Ctx.Web

# Load the groups
$groups = $web.SiteGroups
$Ctx.Load($groups)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Get the SharePoint group
$Group = $groups.GetByName("$title Visitors");
$Ctx.Load($Group);
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$listName = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Internal Files")
$Ctx.Load($listName)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Break inheritance 
$listName.BreakRoleInheritance($true, $false)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# Load the list role assignments
$Ctx.Load($listName.RoleAssignments)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

# remove the visitor group from the list
$listName.RoleAssignments.Groups.Remove($Group)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

But then I am failing to give Full Control to site Members.

Does anyone have a best follow on method please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code:

```
$roleAssignment = $null 
$Group = $Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("$title Members");
$Ctx.Load($Group)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$roleDefs = $Web.RoleDefinitions
$Ctx.Load($roleDefs)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$Permissions = $roleDefs | where {$_.Name -eq "Full Control"}

$roleAssignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($Ctx)
$roleAssignment.Add($Permissions)

$Ctx.Load($listName.RoleAssignments.Add($Group, $roleAssignment))
$listName.Update()
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

[Created from this post.](http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/2012/06/07/scripting-sharepoint-online-with-powershell-using-client-object-model/) You can also look inside and use his code. He has created some functions here.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: Thanks, that sort of works - except that it doesn't know what the role FullControl is. It seems to be looking for these roles: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee536725(v%3Doffice.15)

Not sure any of them are the equivalent? I tried using 'Editor' but it errors with this:

format-default : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code, now I tested and is functionally

Comment: Ah you guys are great! All working - thanks a lot :)

Comment: you're welcome, check it as correct answer, thanks.

Comment: Ahh.. Only thing is it applies it to all document libraries. We just want to do it on particular ones, e.g. "Internal Files", following on from where I have broken the inheritance. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I had $Web for set permissions, edited now for $ListName which you have filled. Now mark it thanks